# visual studio file tabs keep switching back and forth

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure what or where to look for with this:
In visual studio when you open a new file it appears in your file tab next to the others that are already open.
When I have a lot of files pinned to stay open it will switch to display the files on a second line.

Sometimes visual studio thinks after putting the file on the second line there is enough space after all and it switches back on the first line, there not being enough space after all it goes back to the second line and thus an endless cycle starts making my editor useless.

Anyone know what I can do about this?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Professional
```

Comment: Interesting, my VS doesn't ever use two rows for tabs, instead when it gets full there are arrows to navigate back and forth and a dropdown. Possibly you have some extension installed which is the problem, not VS itself? Or I have somehow turned it off but cannot find a related option.

Comment: You have to pin the tabs to stay open, otherwise they indeed disappear into a sort of dropdown. Other than a refactor and cmake tool my vs is pretty vanilla

Comment: Known problem, several existing bug reports at connect.microsoft.com.  [This one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/824454/visual-studio-2013-tabs-start-moving-wildly-from-one-tab-row-to-another-cant-stop-and-have-to-kill-vs-process) is probably best, with recommended workarounds.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks I hope the ticking of pinned tabs fixes this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Known problem, several existing bug reports at connect.microsoft.com. [This one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/824454/visual-studio-2013-tabs-start-moving-wildly-from-one-tab-row-to-another-cant-stop-and-have-to-kill-vs-process) is probably best, with recommended workarounds.

- Hans Passant (comments to question)

> There are a few workarounds, in case you regularly encounter this issue:
>   1.    Display pinned tabs on a separate row from unpinned tabs (Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Show pinned tabs in a separate row).
>   2.    Unpin some tabs, or pin some more tabs.
>   3.    Change the width of the document well containing the tabs, either by resizing the outer window or resizing windows docked to the left or right of the document well. I couple of pixels either way (larger or smaller) should be sufficient.
>   4.    Use a DPI setting other than 125%. We were only able reproduce this issue using a 125% DPI setting.

- Jeff Robison
  Visual Studio IDE [(provided reference)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/824454/visual-studio-2013-tabs-start-moving-wildly-from-one-tab-row-to-another-cant-stop-and-have-to-kill-vs-process)